# Post image to specific album in facebook page using unity and facebook SDK?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

i have problem posting images to my facebook fanpage's album, i can post image to the page's timeline as normal user, how to post them in the album as a page.
i used these permissions email,publish_actions,user_photos,manage_pages,publish_pages

```
    // Read screen contents into the texture

    FB.API("<page_name>?fields=access_token", Facebook.HttpMethod.GET, GetPageAccessToken);

    FB.API("<page_name>/albums?fields=name", Facebook.HttpMethod.GET, GetAlbumID);

    tex.Apply();
    byte[] screenshot = tex.EncodeToPNG();

    var wwwForm = new WWWForm();

    string picName = "Idioman_" + Time.time + ".png";

    wwwForm.AddField("access_token", page_access_token);

    wwwForm.AddBinaryData("image", screenshot, picName);



    Debug.Log("trying to post screenshot");

    FB.API(album_id + "/photos", Facebook.HttpMethod.POST, PostPicCallback, wwwForm);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that you use a [page access token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#pagetokens) for the POST request that you are making to '//photos'.

Looking at your code snippet, I suspect that you are not obtaining that page access token correctly, as the `access_token` field does not exist on the `/<PAGE_ID` endpoint:

```
FB.API("<page_name>?fields=access_token", Facebook.HttpMethod.GET, GetPageAccessToken);
```

Instead, you should be calling `GET /me/accounts` with a user access token for a person that has granted your app the `manage_pages` permission scope, and who can actually act as an editor for the page you wish to upload photos to.